# Count number of elements that has a score

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-ide

Is there a way to count the number of elements that isn't equal to 0.00?

For example, the code is

```
<div id="average_2123" style="font-size:20px; ">0.00</div>
<div id="average_2124" style="font-size:20px; ">23.53</div>
<div id="average_2125" style="font-size:20px; ">0.00</div>
```

How can I count the element so it's only 1 since only one of them has a score?

I want to do this on PHPUnit. I can also do it on Selenium IDE because I can convert it to PHPUnit

Answer (score 1):

you will have to write custom code. I am writing java pseudocode. hope you can understand and convert

```
List<WebElements> ElemList = Webdriver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div")

for (i = 0; i < ElemList.size();i++)
{

          WebElement Current =List.getElementAt(i);
          String ElemName = current.getAttribute("id");
          String text =""
          int Count = 0;  
          if( id.Contains("average"))
          {

              if( !id.getAttribute("value").equals("0.00")
              {
                  count++;
              }


          } 




}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both of your answers were helpful. I had to figure out a way to convert it to PHP even though I don't understand Java.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach can be as mentioned below. Im writing the code in Java:

```
List<WebElement> elemList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id^='average']"));
List<WebElement> filteredElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    for (WebElement element : elemList) {
        if (Long.parseLong(element.getText()) > 0.00)
            filteredElements.add(element);
    }
```

This will be find all the elements whose "id" attribute starts with "average".

Also here i am converting the text to long and then comparing whether its grater than 0.00

The filteredEleemnts are the elements which have value greater than 0.00

Comment: Thanks. Both of your answers were helpful. I had to figure out a way to convert it to PHP even though I don't understand Java.